# I am trying to write a program that counts the occurrences of conjunctions(or words with 1,2 or 3 letters) in C, my code runs but it shows 0 words

Tags: c

I've been trying to make this code for a bit of time but I can't figure it out. I have to find the occurences of conjuctions or words with one, two or three letters in a string.

Can someone please help me figure it out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int stringwordcount(char s[100])
{
    int count = 0;

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(s);i++){

        if((isspace(s[i]-1) || ispunct(s[i]- 1)) && isalpha(s[i]) && isalpha(s[i]+1) && isalpha(s[i]+2) && (isspace(s[i]+3) || ispunct(s[i]+3))){

            count++;

            i+=3;
        } else if((isspace(s[i]-1) || ispunct(s[i]- 1)) && isalpha(s[i]) && isalpha(s[i]+1) && (isspace(s[i]+2) || ispunct(s[i]+2))){

            count++;
            i+=2;
        } else if ((isspace(s[i]-1) || ispunct(s[i]- 1)) && isalpha(s[i]) && (isspace(s[i]+1)|| ispunct(s[i]+1))){

            count++;
            i++;
        }
        return count;
    }

}
int main()
{

    int i, ratiod;

    int maxRatio = 0;

    char maxStr[101];

    char str[101];

    while (fgets(str, 101, stdin) != NULL){

        str[strlen(str)-1] = '\0';

        ratiod = stringwordcount(str);

        if (ratiod > maxRatio){

            maxRatio = ratiod;

            strcpy(maxStr, str);

        }

    }

    printf("%d: ", ratiod);

    puts(maxStr);

    return 0;

}
```

I've been trying to make this code for a bit of time but I can't figure it out. I have to find the occurences of conjuctions or words with one, two or three letters in a string.

Can someone please help me figure it out.

Comment: Two things: First of all you need to pass a *character* to the `is*` functions. I.e. `isalpha(s[i])`; And the second thins is with the loop `for(i = 0; i < strlen(s);i++)`, doing `i + 1` and `i + 2` etc. *will* be out of bounds as indexes.

Comment: What @Someprogrammerdude said, but also you don't have a return statement in your function. Didn't you get a warning message from the compiler?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Explain what you think `isalpha(i)` is doing exactly.

Comment: I think that the out-of-bounds accesses aren't a problem as written, although they for sure look wrong. Because for example the next character is accessed only if the previous character `isalpha`, for which `\0` will return false.

Comment: Also show us the code that calls `stringwordcount`, that could be wrong too.

Comment: Isalpha(i) will check if its a letter or not

Comment: I will show it but the task requires something else this is just a part of the algorithm that i cant figure out.

Comment: Um... `isalpha(i)` checks if `i` (e.g. your *loop counter*) is alpha, which is utterly wrong. You want to check `s[i]`. This mistake is rife all over this code. Literally *every* expression for every `is*` usage.

Comment: The code does not contain any output and does not provide any result to the caller. What does "but it shows 0 words" mean then?

Comment: Even with the fixes above, the code is still wrong, because although the intention is to find words with 1, 2 or 3 letters, the conditions discover words of any length because for example a word with 10 letters will trigger the first condition when i is at the 8th letter of the word.

Comment: You should enable more warnings. For GCC you can use `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic`. That should give a warning about "reaching end of non-void function without returning a value"

Comment: ^^^^ add `-Werror` to that list, because at this juncture I *guarantee* every warning is a logical error of some sort.

Comment: ... and more care needs to be taken at the end of the string. There may be no space or punctuation after the final word. `"this and"` for example contains 1 word of length 3.

Comment: I just fixed some issues, can you check it again if possible

Comment: @Tara you can check it again yourself, by running your code on examples. Thinking up test cases is an important skill in programming.

Comment: that is still wrong `isspace(s[i]- 1)`. `s[i]` is a specific character in your array. `s[i]-1` Is the very same character but you subtract 1 from its value. You probably want to know whether the previous character is a space. That would be `s[i-1]`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

At least this issue:

Instead of passing the *index* to `is...()`, pass the *character*.

```
    // if (isalpha(i) && ...
    if (isalpha(s[i]) && ...
```

Comment: That's just _one_ problem amoung many others

Comment: @Jabberwocky Hence the reason this answer begins with "At least this issue:".  I count at least 11 weaknesses.